# c++ ofstream: evaluate close() error

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to figure out the reason of a failed `ofstream::close()` and encountered some behaviour I don't understand.

I use an `std::ofstream` and `std::copy()` to write data to a stream, then I write the file by using `close()`. If I provoke an error (e.g. the filesystem is full), the `failbit` is set by `close()`, but I'd like to get a more detailed error description.

So far I thought that `errno` is always set if a system call fails. However `errno` says `Success` if I check instantly after `close()` fails.

I'm sure a system call is used when `close()`ing the stream because it will write the file to the filesystem, but then how is it possible that `errno` doesn't tell anything about the problem? So:

- Does `ofstream::close()` not use any system calls?

If I explicitly call `flush()` after `std::copy()`, then `errno` is set properly

```
No space left on device
```

and the `failbit` is set. The subsequent call of `close()` also sets the failbit. Surprisingly `errno` is reset to `success`.

As per `errno` manpage:

```
errno is never set to zero by any system call or library function
```

and I don't see which other function would reset `errno`.

- Does `ofstream::close()` explicitly reset `errno` in case it succeeds?

The documentation on `ofstream` I've found doesn't say anthing about `errno`.

*Tested with Linux x86 g++ 4.7.3.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed ofstream::close() makes multiple system calls. Even though system calls and C library functions do not set errno to zero, C++ libraries may. At least some implementation of ofstream::close() sets errno to 0. See the comment below.

My advice is to pay attention to the documentation on the things you use, and do not make assumptions. In this case, as you pointed out the documentation of ofstream::close() does not say anything about errno, so you should not make any assumption of errno after calling ofstream::close(). On the other hand, C functions such as close(fd) specifically mention errno in the documentation. So if you really need errno, use C functions instead.

Comment: But according to the manpage no system call shall set `errno` to 0 (Success). Using C-functions might be the better alternative in this case,  but then I'll have to waive the advantage of a more general approach (C++ streams).

Comment: My understanding is that the manpage of errno only says no system call or C library will set errno to 0. But It does not limit other code, such as user code or C++ library, from setting errno to 0. I studied the C++ systems source code and found ofstream::close() calls basic_filebuf::close() which calls __basic_file::close() which, according to at least one implementation, sets errno to 0. See https://opensource.apple.com/source/libstdcxx/libstdcxx-52/src/basic_file.cc

Comment: I've accepted already but actually think sth like the following should partially go into the answer : _ofstream::close() may set errno to 0 and does so at least in some implementations_

Comment: You are right @radix. I've edited my answer per your suggestion.